# Metadata error when installing "pyqt6-tools"

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm using Python 3.11. I'm trying to install pyqt6-tools using `pip install pyqt6-tools` command but the following error is occurred during installation:

> C:\Users\Alex>pip install pyqt6-tools Collecting pyqt6-tools   Using
> cached pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB) Collecting click
> Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB) Collecting
> pyqt6==6.1.0   Using cached PyQt6-6.1.0.tar.gz (946 kB)   Installing
> build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build wheel ...
> done   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error   error:
> subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │
> exit code: 1   ╰─> [33 lines of output]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py",
> line 144, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
> hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
>
> ```
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py",
> ```
>
> line 351, in 
> main()
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py",
> line 333, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py",
> line 148, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
> whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py",
> line 46, in build_wheel
> project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 87, in bootstrap
> project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py",
> line 585, in setup
> self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m5ab_lv3\pyqt6_b00490afe1cb4b13bf5a1a49acc55f24\project.py",
> line 60, in apply_user_defaults
> super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py",
> line 70, in apply_user_defaults
> super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py",
> line 236, in apply_user_defaults
> self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
> File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2mc4erbo\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py",
> line 69, in apply_user_defaults
> raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
> sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
> [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is might be a sort of bug, but really more that there isn't an installer yet for your version of python and OS.

You can either try installing an older version of Python, some version of 3.10 would probably do. Or you can try one of the workarounds detailed in the bug report that people have claimed to successfully have used in the [github repo](https://github.com/altendky/pyqt-tools/issues/98#issuecomment-968296553)

The link directs you to instructions for PyQt5, but if you scroll down you will see people claiming that the same process works for PyQt6 and there are specific wheel files you can download.

Comment: I just got the same error with python 3.10.8 when trying to install pyqt6-tools.  Will keep looking to find the version that works :(

Comment: @panofish  There shouldn't be any issues on 3.10

Comment: just tried every version of 3.10.* with clean install and they all failed with error.... only 3.9.13 worked.

Comment: @panofish  then there is something else in your enviornment that is causing it, because I use 3.10 and have been for months and it works fine. and have never had an issue

Comment: I guess it only works if you install using the whl files and not with pip?